# Sitecore ECM: Subscription module

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

I need to insert a Subscription form into a CMS Web page.
I though to re-use the default source code already developed and coming with the ECM package after the installation.

In the Layout/EmailCampaign folder there is an user control: Subscription Form.ascx
In the OnInit method, they are calling another method to retrieve some parameters.

Parameters like Require Authentication, Show List, Target Audience List.

Is there somebody who knows where do I have to define those parameters ? They are all the time empty or null.

Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

Hmm or maybe it's done on the Target Audience you associate to the control. You may be able to add the required parameters when added the control to a layout/sub-layout or when adding through presentation settings.

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are configured when you add the control as a component. You can change the settings when you edit the related item for the component when added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you mention, usually comes from the data-template:
`/sitecore/templates/Email` `Campaign/Subscription` Sublayout Parameters

And you set them where you assign Layout Details to the presentation item:

This applies to my Sitecore 6.5 installation, in the administration content editor:
Choose your item, click `Presentation`, in the `Layout section`, choose `Details`, choose `Edit`, choose the tab `Controls`, locate the sublayout that represents your subscribtion form  and choose `Edit`.

In the following popup you will be able to set the values of the parameters that you mention.

If you don't see the three parameters `Target audience list`, `Require authentication` and `Show list` here, you might have forgotten to assign the datatemplate :
`/sitecore/templates/Email Campaign/Subscription` Sublayout Parameters 
...to your `parameter template` on your Sublayout item.

I suspect the last section to be your real problem, due to the fact that you get null values